# The do-until emulation in bash not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, control-flow, until-loop

I'm trying to do do-until emulation in bash, but is not working. code is below

```
# an emulation of the do-until loop

do_stuff() {

echo "Enter password"
read password         

if [[ $password != "theflow" ]]
   then
     echo " Sorry, try again."
fi   
}

do_stuff

until (( $password == "theflow" ))
 do
  do_stuff
done
```

Comment: I edited your code to use a code block and removed the line numbers, but it would be easier to read if you used consistent indentation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than comparing `$password` in two separate places, I think that it would make more sense to use the return code of your function to indicate whether the check is successful or not:

```
check_password () {
  read -rsp 'Enter password: ' password

  if [[ $password != 'theflow' ]]; then
    echo 'Sorry, try again.' >&2
    return 1
  fi

  return 0
}
```

Then your `until` loop can be:

```
until check_password; do
  :
done
```

Which will keep calling `check_password` until it returns `0` (success).

I made a couple more changes to your code, based on suggestions in the comments (thanks!):

I have used `read -rsp` to do the following:

- `-r` disable interpretation of `\` as escape character (you almost always want this one)
- `-s` silent mode - don't echo characters
- `-p 'Enter password: '` display prompt, avoiding the need to `echo` separately

I also sent the error message to stderr using `>&2`.

Note that `(( $password == "theflow" ))` will not behave as you expect, because the comparison is being performed in an arithmetic context. You should use `[[` to compare strings.

Comment: Merge echo to built-in read prompt, add `-r` flag and silence output `read -rsp "Enter password: " password`. Add quotes around variable `if [ "$password" != 'theflow' ]; then`. Send failure message to stderr `echo ' Sorry, try again.' >&2`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was trying to minimise the number of changes I made to the OP's code in order to make it work. I've update `read` and `echo` but the quotes aren't needed in `[[`, so I'll keep that as it is.

Comment: thank you Tom Fenech, I changed the parentheses in the until loop, now it worked.